# How do I put API Gateway in front of ALB and then to ECS/EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-elb, aws-alb

I am Building a solution, where I have 10-15 micro-services REST Applications running in ECS Container and few will be in EC2. I am using Cognito as API Gateway authentication. Now UI Application will send the request to API Gateway, which in turn connect with REST Application and returns the response.

I have tried implementing API Gateway authentication with Cognito and I am able to connect to the REST endpoint running in EC2.

Now I need a solution like **API Gateway -> Application Load Balancer -> Target Group -> ECS/EC2** will be running in Public Subnet.

How do I Configure this?

Am I following the correct approach?

Comment: Your question still not clear what exactly are you looking ,are you looking how to configure api getway then cognito then load balancer then ec2 or ecs

Comment: Just point API Gateway to the URL of the load balancer instead of the URL of the ECS/EC2 instance. Are you running into some sort of issue here? What is the problem you are encountering exactly?

Comment: The question seems to be about injecting ALB in the middle. If you are using API-Gateway just for cognito auth, you can now do it directly on the ALB: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/

Answer (score -1):

- Api getway you need to expose your microservice and cognito authorizer will take care authentication and authorization.

To register your  instances using the console

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
- On the navigation pane, under LOAD BALANCING, choose Load Balancers.
- Select your load balancer.
- In the bottom pane, select the Instances tab.
- Choose Edit Instances.
- Select the instance to register with your load balancer.
- Choose Save.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-deregister-register-instances.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-load-balancer.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-application-load-balancer.html

Answer (score -1):

When you setup your API Gateway,

Create a proxy resource with a greedy path {proxy+}. 
Set ANY Method on the proxy resource.
Set the endpoint URL to your ALB endpoint.

Ex. ENDPOINT URL:
https://alb-example-123456789.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/example/{proxy}

For more details, refer to this links:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html?shortFooter=true

Comment: Why has this been marked down, it actually provides useful information towards solving the OP's problem?